# Elasticsearch: sort by value and dynamic templates

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need sorting for the documents like :

```
{
  customer: {
    fullname: "Lorem ipsum"
  },
  order_number: "12313131",
  company: {
    name: "Test Inc."
  },
  date: "10.06.2015 18:00"
}
```

But as far as I unterstood I can not sort by values in analysed fields. There I am trying to create a mapping :

```
 { 
      "mappings": { 
        "_default_": { 
          "dynamic_templates": [ 
            { 
              "base": { 
                "match": "*", 
                "mapping": { 
                  "type": "multi_field", 
                  "fields": { 
                    "{name}": {"type": "string"}, 
                    "_sort": {"type": "string", "analyzer": "sort"} 
                  } 
                } 
              } 
            } 
          ] 
        } 
      }, 
      "settings": { 
        "analysis": { 
          "analyzer": { 
            "sort": { 
              "type": "custom", 
              "tokenizer": "keyword", 
              "filter": "lowercase" 
            } 
          } 
        } 
      } 
    }
```

But if I put this configuration, I am getting an exception : ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: unknown property. Without this mapping my indexing works fine.

What i want to do is create a multifield called name_sort (not_analysed) so I can sort by values.

```
**** 
At leas I can able to create a mapping correctly. My mapping looks like: 

 {
  "muhamo": {
    "mappings": {
      "bookings": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "base": {
              "mapping": {
                "index": "analyzed",
                "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                "fields": {
                  "{name}_sort": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "{dynamic_type}"
                  }
                }
              },
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "catch_all": {
              "mapping": {
                "fields": {
                  "{name}_sort": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "{dynamic_type}"
                  }
                }
              },
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "*"
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "bookingType": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "bookingType_sort": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "comment": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "comment_sort": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "costLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "costLocation_sort": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "customer": {
            "properties": {
              "fullname": {
                "type": "string",
                "fields": {
                  "fullname_sort": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "date_sort": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "deleted": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "toAirport": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I try to sort my results by customer.fullname_sort I am getting an exception as

```
 query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No mapping found for [customer.fullname_sort] in order to sort on]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sort on `customer.fullname.fullname_sort`. That's the path to your field, according to the mapping of the index.